# Why doesn't SharedWorker expose exactly 1 port per client?

Tags: javascript, port, shared-worker

[Docs for the SharedWorker connect event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorkerGlobalScope/connect_event)

[Docs for the `ports` property itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/ports)

Here's example code which takes a client connection and references a port; this code runs as a SharedWorker (e.g. `worker.js`):

```js
onconnect = evt => {
  
  // Client connection represented by `evt`
  
  const port = evt.ports[0];
  port.onmessage = msg => {
    // Client sent us something, represented by `msg`
    // We can reply with `port.postMessage`
  };
  
};
```

Why is an *array* of (i.e. potentially a plurality of) ports exposed? When will a `SharedWorker` ever have more than one port per client, and what would multiple ports represent in such a case? Two different ports connecting the same two agents? (Is there some potential to increase bandwidth at an OS-level by making more ports available??)

The above code ignores all ports other than first - is it always better to use the following instead?

```js
onconnect = evt => {
  
  // Client connection represented by `evt`
    
  for (const port of evt.ports) {
    
    // For each client port, listen to messages on that port (?)
    port.onmessage = msg => {
      // Client sent us something, represented by `msg`
      // We can reply with `port.postMessage`
    };
    
  }
  
};
```

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API#channel_messaging_concepts_and_usage) say that when you create a MessageChannel, it has **two** ports.   The app that created the channel uses `port1` to send messages to the other end, and the app at the other end of the port uses `port2` to send messages back to the creator.

Comment: I believe `MessageChannel` is used behind the scenes to implement `SharedWorker` - it seems only a single port appears in the `SharedWorkerGlobalScope` (when I run the above code, `evt.ports.length` has always been `1` so far)